# Prove that two parallelograms have the same area

Tags: geometry

[image: Drawing]

In the picture there are two parallelograms. How can I prove they have the same area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the triangle $BFG$ and argue that it has area equal to half of both parallelograms area.

Comment: I have proved it. What next should I do?

Comment: It follows that these parallelograms have equal areas because their halves are equal. In other words, if $\frac 12 a = \frac 12 b$, then $a=b$.

Answer (score 1):

> Sliding the red parallelogram to the green one, and then the blue.

[image]